# How to define a discrete distribution with non-integer sample space elements (outcomes)?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, piecewise

## How to define a discrete distribution with non-integer states (sample space elements)?

I know how to define a discrete distribution with integer states:

```
  state:       1        2       3
P[X==state]   0.3      0.4     0.3
```

I want to define a discrete distribution with non-integer states:

```
  state:      0.01     0.02    0.03
P[X==state]   0.3      0.4     0.3
```

---

It is possible to use `Piecewise[]` and `ProbabilityDistribution[]` to define a distribution with integer states.

```
pmf[x_] := Piecewise[{
      {0.3, x == 1}
    , {0.4, x == 2}
    , {0.3, x == 3}
    }];
distribution = ProbabilityDistribution[pmf[x], {x, 1, 3, 1}];
```

[image]

#### But `ProbabilityDistribution[]` seems unable to work with non-integer states (it even does not work with integer states with jumps of $dx=2$)

Is this a bug or a feature or a convention?

[image]

---

### Question.

> How do I define the non-integer state distribution (above)?

## Attempt

```
pmf[x_] := Piecewise[{
          {0.3, x == 0.01}
        , {0.4, x == 0.02}
        , {0.3, x == 0.03}
        }];
distribution = ProbabilityDistribution[pmf[x], {x, 0.01, 0.03, 0.01}];

Probability[X > .02, X \[Distributed] distribution]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is with `WeightedData` and `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[WeightedData[{0.01, 0.02, 0.03}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.3}]]
PDF[dist, x]
```

> 0.3 Boole[0.01 == x] + 0.4 Boole[0.02 == x] + 0.3 Boole[0.03 == x]

*edit*

Actually, you can also use:

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.3, 0.4, 0.3} -> {0.01, 0.02, 0.03}]
```

which is a bit shorter.

Comment: `dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.3, 0.4, 0.3} -> {0.01, 0.02, 0.03}]` is very nice. I'll use this from now on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) using your first `distribution`:

```
ClearAll[tr]
Table[tr[i] = .01 i, {i, 1, 3}];
td = TransformedDistribution[tr[x], Distributed[x, distribution]];

Probability[t > .02, Distributed[t, td]]
```

> 0.3

```
Mean[td]
```

> 0.02

```
PDF[td, t] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  0.3 & t=0.01\lor t=0.03 \\
>  0.4 & t=0.02
> \end{cases}$