# How to define conditioned random variables / distribution in mathematica?

Tags: distributions

> Consider a simple case,
>
> - $X_1$ defined as $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=q$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1=-1)=1-q$
> - $X_2|\{X_1=1\}$ defined as $\mathbb{P}(X_2=1|X_1=1)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_2=-1|X_1=1)=1-p$
> - $X_2|\{X_1=-1\}$ defined as $\mathbb{P}(X_2=1|X_1=-1)=1-p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_2=-1|X_1=-1)=p$

In Mathematica, distribution of $X_1$ can be defined as follows:

```
X1 = TransformedDistribution[2x-1,{x\[Distributed]BernoulliDistribution[q]}]
```

How does one define the conditional distribution $X_2|X_1$ or joined distribution $X_1,X_2$?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to construct the joint probability function rather that expect *Mathematica* to put that together automatically from the one marginal distribution and the conditional probabilities.  But after that one can use *Mathematica* commands to find conditional probabilities, marginal distributions, etc.

```
(* Known information ... *)
(* Pr(X1 = 1) *)
p1 = q;
(* Conditional probabilities: Pr(X2 | X1) *)
c[1, 1] = p        (* Pr(X2=1 | X1=1)  *)
c[1, -1] = 1 - p   (* Pr(X2=1 | X1=-1) *)

(* Construct joint probabilities: Pr(X1 & X2) *)
pr[1, 1] = p1 c[1, 1]
pr[1, -1] = p1 (1 - c[1, 1])
pr[-1, 1] = (1 - p1) c[1, -1]
pr[-1, -1] = (1 - p1) (1 - c[1, -1])

(* Define a joint probability function for use in ProbabilityFunction *)
joint[x1_, x2_] := Boole[x1 == -1 && x2 == -1]*pr[-1, -1] +
  Boole[x1 == -1 && x2 == 1]*pr[-1, 1] +
  Boole[x1 == 1 && x2 == -1]*pr[1, -1] +
  Boole[x1 == 1 && x2 == 1]*pr[1, 1]

(* Turn this into a Mathematica joint probability distribution *)
d = ProbabilityDistribution[joint[x1, x2], {x1, -1, 1, 2}, {x2, -1, 1, 2}];

(* Find conditional probabilities *)
Probability[x2 == -1 \[Conditioned] x1 == -1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] d]
(* p *)
Probability[x2 == -1 \[Conditioned] x1 == 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] d]
(* 1-p *)
Probability[x2 == 1 \[Conditioned] x1 == -1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] d]
(* 1-p *)
Probability[x2 == 1 \[Conditioned] x1 == 1, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] d]
(* p *)

(* Marginal distributions *)
FullSimplify[PDF[MarginalDistribution[d, 1], x1]]
```

[image: Marginal probability of X1]

```
FullSimplify[PDF[MarginalDistribution[d, 2], x2]]
```

[image: Marginal probability of X2]

```
(* Mean of marginal distributions *)
Mean[MarginalDistribution[d, 1]]
(* -1+2 q *)
Mean[MarginalDistribution[d, 2]]
(* 1-2 p-2 q+4 p q *)
```

***Addition:***

Stealing from @SjoerdSmit 's answer ([How to define a discrete distribution with non-integer sample space elements (outcomes)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201913/how-to-define-a-discrete-distribution-with-non-integer-sample-space-elements-ou)) one can also define the joint distribution in the following manner:

```
d = EmpiricalDistribution[{pr[-1, -1], pr[-1, 1], pr[1, -1], pr[1, 1]} ->
                            {{-1, -1},   {-1, 1},   {1, -1},   {1, 1}}]
```

This is probably a safer way to define the joint probability distribution as you can see the match-ups between the probabilities and the pairs of (X1,X2) values.